# How to overflow grid column with another column @media

Tags: css, reactjs, web, css-grid, styled-components

I have 2 rows and 2 columns in `grid-template-areas: "a a" "b c"`. I am trying to overflow column B with column c when screen width is less than some value (for example 1100px), but when I change browser size column c start to run out of the screen instead of float above column b. `grid-template-columns: auto 230px`; `grid template-rows: 56px auto`;.
Whole site looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/a5gb0c7p/
Column "elem1", "elem2" and "child2" have predefined size. "child top" and "child1" are auto, but "child1" is a column which show email message, so it will have calculated width at some point.

TLDR: While resizing i want to float column c above column b (in code editor: float column "child2" above "child1") when web width is less than some value

Answer (score 0):

If I think I've understood you correctly you want the grid to change at a certain screen width?

Would this be the kind of effect you're after?
https://jsfiddle.net/jimmythehat/x548ewf9/5/

When the browser gets below 800px, the media query fires and changes the grid structure.

Code below:

```
.parent2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 230px;
  grid-template-rows: 56px auto;
  grid-template-areas: "child0 child0"
                      "child1 child2";
  background: orange;
  border: 5px dotted blue;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
  .parent2 {
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "child0"
                       "child2" 
                        "child1";
  }
}
```